# How to remove damage immunity?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

After you attack a player or mob, they are invincible for around 0.5 seconds, and hits do not register to the mob/player's health. I am trying to remove this damage immunity so that all hits register to the mob/player's health for this server I'm working on, so I looked for behavior packs that would do it, however I can only find damage immunity-related content associated with Java edition, which I cannot use. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by “remove damage immunity”, what exactly is your issue, people are invincible?

Comment: By "damage immunity", I mean this: After you attack a player or mob, they are invincible for around 0.5 seconds, and hits do not register to the mob/player's health. I am trying to remove this damage immunity so that all hits register to the mob/player's health.

Comment: keep in kind with that in place you could kill a person with full armor in like 1 second if you just spam fast.

Comment: That doesn't help answer my question; and there is also kb that will probably create space between the players.

Comment: If you’re talking to me I... wasn’t trying to answer your question? I literally just made a comment bro, that wasn’t an answer at all that’s why it’s not in the answer section

Comment: your request for clarification is not an answer and doesn't help. if you want to comment it has to be helpful

Comment: that was helpful. Anyway I'm not falling for your bait